# bz2 module fails when building Python 3.7

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, android-ndk, bz2

I'm trying to cross compile Python 3.7 for Android.  I see in my output that bz2 if failing with the following error

```
building '_bz2' extension
/home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/sdk/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -isystem /home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/build/19c-22-aarch64-linux-androideabi-4.9/include -isystem /home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/build/19c-22-aarch64-linux-androideabi-4.9/include/openssl -no-integrated-as -I. -I./Include -target aarch64-none-linux-androideabi22 -target aarch64-none-linux-androideabi22 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -fPIC -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I./Include -I. -I/home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/src/Python-3.7.3/Include -I/home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/src/Python-3.7.3 -c /home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/src/Python-3.7.3/Modules/_bz2module.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/src/Python-3.7.3/Modules/_bz2module.o
/home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/sdk/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -isystem /home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/build/19c-22-aarch64-linux-androideabi-4.9/include -isystem /home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/build/19c-22-aarch64-linux-androideabi-4.9/include/openssl -no-integrated-as -shared -target aarch64-none-linux-androideabi22 -fuse-ld=lld -L /home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/build/19c-22-aarch64-linux-androideabi-4.9/lib -target aarch64-none-linux-androideabi22 -fuse-ld=lld -L /home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/build/19c-22-aarch64-linux-androideabi-4.9/lib -target aarch64-none-linux-androideabi22 -fuse-ld=lld -L /home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/build/19c-22-aarch64-linux-androideabi-4.9/lib -fPIC -target aarch64-none-linux-androideabi22 build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/src/Python-3.7.3/Modules/_bz2module.o -L. -L/home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/build/19c-22-aarch64-linux-androideabi-4.9/lib -lbz2 -lpython3.7m -o build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.7/_bz2.cpython-37m.so
ld.lld: error: /home/dematic/SPE/python3-android/build/19c-22-aarch64-linux-androideabi-4.9/lib/libbz2.a(bzlib.o) is incompatible with aarch64linux
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am building bzip2 1.0.6 without any issues, but I assume I'm not linking to it correctly or some other issue. Is there some sort of other architecture I'm supposed to be building?

This is the project I'm trying to build with
https://github.com/GRRedWings/python3-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to cross compile Python 3.7 for Android. I see in my output that bz2 if failing with the following error

The Bzip2 makefiles are not written for cross-compiles. They effectively ignore a user's flags like `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. The makefiles actually blows away a user's `CFLAGS` and sets it to `CFLAGS=-Wall -Winline -O2 -g $(BIGFILES)`. Your flags like `-target aarch64-none-linux-androideabi22` are not used.

There are two Makefiles in play. One is called `Makefile` and it builds the static library, if I recall correctly. The second is `Makefile-libbz2_so`, and it build the shared object. You need to fix the omissions and apply the fixes to both makefiles.

You should probably use a patched Bzip like [bzip2-noloader](https://github.com/noloader/bzip2-noloader). It honors a user's `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, etc. The check-in of interest is [Commit 34d170f31106](https://github.com/noloader/bzip2-noloader/commit/34d170f31106).

The makefile recipes in [bzip2-noloader](https://github.com/noloader/bzip2-noloader) look similar to the following. They preserve Seward's original settings in `BZIP_CFLAGS`. But they also utilize `CPPFLAGS` and allow a user override in `CFLAGS`. The override will pickup your flags like `-target aarch64-none-linux-androideabi22`.

```
blocksort.o: blocksort.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(BZIP_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c blocksort.c
```

Programs use `LDFLAGS` as expected:

```
bzip2: libbz2.a bzip2.o
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(BZIP_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o bzip2 bzip2.o -L. -lbz2
```

Finally, the [bzip2-noloader](https://github.com/noloader/bzip2-noloader) fork also honor's `PREFIX`, `DESTDIR`, etc. So you can perform staged installs, too.

---

> I am building bzip2 1.0.6 without any issues ...

You are probably building for i686 or x86_64, and not Aarch64. The problem does not surface until link time. You can use `objdump` to inspect the object files, if interested.

---

Also note the makefile does this:

```
CC=gcc
AR=ar
RANLIB=ranlib
LDFLAGS=
```

You may need to tweak those variable assignments, too. Sometimes `ar` and `ranlib` use unusual names, like `ranlib-5.0`. And also be sure the tools are on-path.

---

The way to write makefiles to avoid these sorts of problems is detailed at [7.2.3 Variables for Specifying Commands](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command-Variables.html#Command-Variables) in the GNU Coding Standards. The short of it is, (1) leave `CFLAGS` (and friends) for the user; and (2) *if* a flag is needed, then always supply it.

The GNU Coding Standards uses this as an example:

```
CFLAGS = -g
ALL_CFLAGS = -I. $(CFLAGS)
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CFLAGS) $<
```

Users can override the default `CFLAGS` of `-g`, and `-I` is always added because it is needed for the compile.

Comment: In the patch file I have attached here, a lot of the items you have brought out have been handled.  
https://github.com/GRRedWings/python3-android/blob/master/mk/bzip2/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6-makefile-env.patch

I guess I need to look at the objdump you reference and see if I can figure out if it's true I'm building 64bit.

Comment: in running the objdump it is saying architeecture is i386:x86-64

Comment: @GREnvoy - It looks like the Python build system is hiding output from you. I think you need to see what is behind *`building '_bz2' extension...`*. There has to be more than one object file `_bz2module.o`. With Autoconf you use `V=1`, and with Cmake you use `VERBOSE=1`. I don't know what to use for Python. Here is what I see with modified Makefiles and an ARM dev-board: [Bzip2 ARM build](https://pastebin.com/M6KeUZU8); and an Aarhc64 dev-board: [Bzip2 Aarch64 build](https://pastebin.com/pdYuXfYN).